# Nesting loops and creating a pattern

Tags: c, loops

I am having difficulties on creating a pattern program for one of my assignments. The instructor wants us to create a program that asks for the user to input the width and height, and then print out a pattern of "*" based on what was inputted. I am able to print the entire rectangle, but she wants it to be a specific pattern. The first two and last to rows should be filled with stars, and the lines in between should look like the example I provided below. The rules that must follow is the width must be a multiple of 6 and the height must be greater

Example of pattern:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111
111   111   111   111   111   111   
   111   111   111   111   111   111
111   111   111   111   111   111   
111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

My Code:

```
int width, height, i, j, space;
//Program asks user to enter width of their fabric
printf("What is the width of your fabric?\n");
scanf("%d", &width);
while(width % 6 !=0){
    printf("Please enter a width that is a multiple of 6\n");
    scanf("%d", &width);
}

//Program asks user to enter height of their fabric
printf("What is the height of your fabric?\n");
scanf("%d", &height);
while(height <= 6 || height % 2 == 0){
    printf("Please enter an odd height which is at least 7\n");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    }

for(i=1; i<=height; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=width; j++)
    {
    printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");       
}
```

Comment: Should only the middle rows be shorter? Be clear on how the pattern looks when you're using 9 rows etc.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Say what exactly the "difficulties" are, tell us what input you give, and show us what the complete output should be for that input, and what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. The inner pattern should be ***___***___*** etc. the ___ represents spaces. but it should be 3 "*" followed by 3 "_" until the end of the row.

Answer (score 0):

You need an if-statement inside your loop and adapt the width, depending on what row (variable i) is printed. 
You might want to rename i to currentRow and j to currentColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. The variable `flip` flips 'xxx   ' pattern to '   xxx' on alternate lines.

```
        int flip = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            if (i <= 2 || i >= height - 1)
            {
                // the top two & bottom two lines are solid '*'
                for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flip = 1 - flip;
                for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
                {
                    // repeating pattern: three '*' followed by three ' '
                    // Divide column by 3 (no remainder) and see whether the result is odd or even
                    // subtract 1 so each group of 3 has same result when divided by 3
                    if ( ((j-1)/3) % 2 == flip )
                        printf("*");
                    else
                        printf(" ");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

Comment: John thank you so much for your help. This appears to be almost there. Instead of the middle lining up they should alternate 3 "*" 3 "_" and the next line would start 3"_" 3 "*"

Answer (score -1):

Haha funny.  You think it is a fabric pattern.  From my experience, you take ascii and pull a rom bit pattern from a ROM table array.  I assume that this is not what it is and it is a scalar pattern with height and width
You should use floating point and just take the height and width and scale the pattern to size.  It is not that hard unless you are thinking of doing fixed point math that is related to game programming.  To make it easy think like a scalar matrix of data.
Here is some code that may help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int index=90;
float mynumber[index];
float scalar=2.25;
mynumber[abs(scalar)]=1;
printf("%f\n",mynumber[abs(scalar)]);
return 0;
}
```